# How do I print a list of what has been selected in an Excel dropdown list?

Tags: excel, printing, filter, pivot-table

I am adding some improvements to a spreadsheet that was passed along to me which includes a great deal of manual processing.  I need to program in a list to compare some qualitative data against.  This list is in the form of checked boxes from a pivot table list and I would like to extract (ideally to cells but at least to print) the list that is selected from the filter.  This includes hundreds of selections, so I do not want to manually copy those out and there does not seem to be a list out there.  How can I print out the list of what is being filtered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.  I just temporarily moved the selected fields into the rows, removed the row fields, and then copied and pasted the values onto a new sheet.  Then I returned the pivot sections to their original places and all of the selections remained intact throughout.